# Is there a registry key I can add to an installed service to make it appear in Services.msc

Tags: windows, service, registry, regedit

Is there a registry key I can add to the registry of an installed service that is currently "hidden" from `Services.msc` for whatever reason to make it display in `Services.msc`

I wanted to make some additional services appear in `Services.msc` so I could use the controls and hide some that I want to be considered permanently disabled but I can't find anything about it.

How does `Services.msc` decide what services to show and which ones to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by changing a registry key, In my example I will show you how to expose the controls for `TrustedInstaller` (Windows Update) in `Services.msc`

Open `regedit.exe` and go to the following path

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\`

Find the Service you want to display in `Services.msc` ours is `TrustedInstaller`

[image]

Change the `Display Name` and `Description` to something human readable and then `Restart Your Computer`

Now when you open `Services.msc` you can control the `Service`

[image]